# Analysis of Algorithms: Why Average Case Analysis depends on Probability & Distribution of Inputs

Tags: algorithm

I was studying Analysis of Algorithms.It was fun until i get into Average Case Analysis.Unlike Worst & Best case, Average Case is not mathematically straightforward.In finding Worst & Best case, I could use existing clues (such as For Worst case: fond a case that takes maximum amount of operations/time) to start finding them.However, in Average Case such clues aren't available.In order to identify **what is the average case ?** I've to assume Probability & Distribution of Inputs.But i am not finding very simple explanation & example which clearly helps me to realize that,Why Average Case Analysis depends on  **Probability**  & **Distribution** of Inputs.Please help me with your simple & convincing explanation & example.thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can think of it by reasoning that average case is ideally an average of actual cases in real-life. And an "actual case" of time/space complexity is dependent on actual input.

But if the dependence is not linear, you cannot calculate with an average input to get an average complexity, you need to take the whole distribution of inputs into account.

E.g. for comparing complexity of sorting algorithms when creating [timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), an insight was used that the input arrays/lists are not random, but usually contain already pre-sorted areas - so real-life sample data were collected and used for the analysis / performance tests...

I am not sure what exactly was meant in the literature you are studying by Probability&Distribution, most likely that for continuous/discrete functions there are 2 related concepts: [“probability density function” and “cumulative distribution function”](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175850/difference-between-probability-density-function-and-probability-distribution), that we can treat as synonymous in this context.

Comment: Thanks @Aprillion for quick reply, **if the dependence is not linear**- are you referring it with **dependence between time and actual input**.Also you didn't said anything about **Probability**.Can you please explain a little bit more.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to define *any* average, you have to know what the things are you're averaging over, and how likely each is.

Here the things you're averaging over are the number of operations of a program with a particular input.

So you need to know what are the the possible inputs, and how likely each is. You can call that the probability distribution of inputs, but that makes it sound more complicated than it is.

For example, you might analyse the average number of comparisons performed by quicksort on a randomly shuffled array containing the numbers 1...N. Then the possible inputs are all permutations of the set `{1,2,...,N}`, and each possible input is equally likely (and therefore has probability 1/N!). Computing the average is not so easy, but you can find a derivation in most good Algorithms books (for example: Sedgewick).